# Mac wont sleep - Catalina

Tags: catalina, sleep-wake

Ive got a 2017, 15" MBP, running OSX 10.15.7 but it will not go into sleep mode.

See screenshot from system preferences, any ideas ?

[image: energy saver - battery tab]

[image: energy saver - power adapter]

Comment: Issue the command `pmset -g`.  Post the output

Comment: When you say doesn't go to sleep, do you mean putting the screen down keeps the screen on? or the screen is off but machine is clearly running (it might be busy processing something and can't sleep yet, and this process never completes)? or have you also tried pressing the 'sleep' button in the menubar (Apple button)

Comment: @Allan please see screenshot of terminal here : https://imgur.com/a/8D1GG6t

Comment: @BenButterworth (i have the laptop connected to an external display via a USB C to HDMI adaptor) The screen stays on an the active user stays logged in if the laptop is left. If the laptop lid is closed the external montior still stays on with the active user logged in

Comment: Two things @sam - please post the output here as text, not as a screen shot.  You can get the output directly into your clipboard by piping it to `pbcopy`  (`pmset -g | pbcopy`) then paste.  Second, from what I saw, you've got three processes preventing it.